# How do I stop php from returning headers when I pcntl_fork()?

Tags: php, header, fork, shared-memory

It seems that my php prints X-Powered-By and Content-Type headers for every child made by pcntl_fork().  this wouldn't be a problem if it didn't print them in the middle of the output.

So, for instance, this toy script:

```
function very_long_process($shm){
    sleep(20);
    shm_put_var($shm,0,'terminated');
}
function iterate_until_terminated($shm){
    $signal = shm_get_var($shm,0);
    if($signal=='running'){
        $j = shm_get_var($shm,1);
        $j++;
        shm_put_var($shm,1,$j);
        sleep(2);
        iterate_until_terminated($shm);
    }
    else{
        exit;
    }
}
$shm = shm_attach(ftok(tempnam('/tmp','PHP'),'a'),1000000);
shm_put_var($shm,0,'running');
$i=0;
shm_put_var($shm,1,$i);
$pid = pcntl_fork();
if($pid==0){
    iterate_until_terminated($shm);
}
very_long_process($shm);
while (pcntl_waitpid(0, $status) != -1) {
    $status = pcntl_wexitstatus($status);
}
$iterated = shm_get_var($shm,1);
$signal = shm_get_var($shm,0);
echo "<p>iterated $iterated times.";
echo "<p>process was $signal";
```

Produces the output (in a browser):

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Content-type: text/html

<p>iterated 10 times.<p>process was terminated
```

I've read, and would like to believe, that the solution is to use ob_start() and ob_end_clean(), but I've tried that in a couple places and it didn't work, although (weirdly) with ob_end_flush() I was able to keep the number of extra header pairs to two.  So uh.. where to buffer output?

Of course, I'd be just as happy with a solution that didn't involve output buffering.

Thanks for your help!

Edit:
This particular *toy* fork is meant to simulate passing a request to a model, reading its output stream of data with a view, and then translating that via a templating engine to be picked up by a periodic ajax request.

I know there are probably lots of things wrong with that, but I don't want to get off-topic here.  Is there a way to suppress the headers?

Comment: As you can tell, it's a *bad idea* to fork a PHP script when it's in the middle of serving a request.  If you're using Apache and mod_php, the fork actually also forks Apache.  This is undoubtedly not what you intended.  Can you tell us more about what the long running process is doing?  There are *lots* of better ways to handle long running background tasks, but we'd need to know more in order to recommend one to you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure apache is adding those headers, not php.  That is why output buffering is not working.  You'll have to get those turned off in apache.

Comment: `X-Powered-By: PHP...` is only ever emitted from PHP itself.  Apache is not sending those headers without being told to by PHP.